# Is it okay to share a customer appreciation email I received with my manager?

Tags: management

I received an email wherein a customer congratulated my work.

Is it okay if I forward and share this with my manager?

Comment: It's okay, although the ulterior motive will be transparent.

Comment: thanks for all the comments , i had forwarded the email and got an return email appreciation from manager

Comment: It doesn't just mean you did well, it means the people who set you up for success did well too! A good manager should appreciate these things as it reflects well on the whole organization.

Answer (score 50):

These types of things can affect your performance appraisal, so sure send it on. I always do. Don't worry about being "transparent", there is nothing inherently wrong with wanting your boss to know that someone (especially a client!) likes your work. He also might be pretty happy to be able to tell his boss that his staff is getting compliments from the clients. After all bosses get performance appraisals too and they tend to be more aware of the politics behind them.

I'll point out that your boss is almost certainly copied on any negative feedback anyone has about you, so this makes sure they get a balanced picture. It really is not just bragging.

Comment: Completely agree here.  Its not like you solicited the praise.  Pass that on to your manager, it is your job to make sure that your manager is aware of things like this if they get left out of the chain.  This is true of internal customers(in your company) as well as external customers(your clients).

Comment: I think a great way to subtley share the email is to respond to your customer in thanks, and either CC or BCC your boss.

Comment: My boss *expects* positive emails to be forwarded to her - it goes in the file for performance reviews.

Answer (score 16):

Of course it's okay - there's no reasonable expectation of confidentiality and you should be highlighting your success. What does take care, however, is how you present it. I'd suggest mentioning it in person, perhaps:

"Oh, did I mention that Client A sent me a lovely email? Oh, I'll forward it over. They seem really impressed with what we've done

It's pretty transparent, but you're giving him the chance to share in the success while avoiding sounding cocky about it.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. Part of their job duty is to ensure that you are doing your job properly and you are helping them do their job by giving them the feedback they need. A ton of emails from satisfied customers every week - that's probably a different story. In which case, you have to be selective and just send the ones that strike your fancy in terms of originality, put you in the best light, etc. :) Nothing wrong with doing something that helps your manager do their job and makes you happy at the same time :)

Comment: I'll note that the OP said "MY manager", which indicates that the OP has only one manager. So the use of the word "their" is out of place :) I like to use the word "she" for figures of authority because the inherent cultural assumption in standard English is that the authority figure is male and I want to do my part to combat that assumption. And yes, I am a male myself :)

Comment: Use of "their" is used due to represent a person previously mentioned whose gender is unknown. "Their" is being used as a singular reference. Multiple would have been "their managers" I edited your answer as it was the top on at present to prevent confusion for future readers who may wish to answer. I'm not really sure if this is the place to combat male managers in vast quantity in the workplace but I may be mistaken :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: Thanks to both of you: I learn something new every day :) You just reminded me why learning English was such a pain :)

Comment: In reality, native speakers will use "their" to avoid either appearing to be sexist by using "he" or appearing to be subtly accusing the reader of being sexist by using "she". Back when the prohibition against "their" was strict, it was standard to use  "he" for someone of unknown gender. If one objects to that, one should not object to "their".

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. If a customer goes to the trouble of thanking you in writing, they *intended* to provide you with evidence that You Done Good and deserve praise (at least) from management.

If they're really clueful, they may have sent a copy direct to your management as well.

Comment: Exactly.  When I send such an email after receiving good service, I try to include their manager when possible.  Managers tend to only hear from the customers when something has gone wrong - so it's nice for them to hear something positive about their staff once in awhile.

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you my personal experience.  Its been 7 years in IT now. I have received such emails from customers time to time where in few cases managers were not copied. 
My personal take on this matter will is , if your manager seems nice guy/lady and supports you in general then share it. If you are planning to switch in near future then also share it.
However, if and your manager are of same age and if your manager's manager look at you as next manager then don't share it. Believe it or not your manager may sound like he appreciate your work in this scenario but he/she doesn't internally.

Take call of judgement and proceed.

Comment: Who emails IT about when you did a good job? I've only *ever* gotten emails asking for more help because something's broken. You must've worked *really* hard...

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly fine. The end goal of any business is to keep the customer happy. In case your customer is praising you for your work/efforts, your manager will be more than happy to know about it. It will add on to the trust your manager has on you and your abilities. It also reflects good on the manager as he is the one who is managing you. Hence, go ahead and share it!

Comment: I think we all shaping up a consensus pretty quickly :)